# Disk full while importing a large sql dump

Tags: mariadb

I have a Linux server with 2 disk mounted on it. The OS is installed on disk 1 (capacity 500GB) and disk 2 is for storage (capacity 10TB).

I have a large SQL dump (300GB) located on disk 2, and while importing the file to MariaDB, disk 1 is fill up all the way which crashes the import process.

I don't understand what's happening because there should be enough storage for the whole database to sit on disk 1. When I check the disk usage using

```
du -sh /*
```

The whole OS only take up about 280GB
but when I check with command

```
df -h
```

It shows the partition is full.

Also when I stop MariaDB with command

```
systemctl stop MariaDB
```

instantly 256GB is freed. I reckon some kind of buffer is allocated while importing the SQL file and because the SQL dump is too big, the buffer is going out of hand (but I might be wrong).

Is there anything that I can do to limit the buffer that MariaDB allocate so my disk won't fill up while importing the file.

Edit:

Disk 2 is mounted at `/data`

Mariadb version is 10.4.28

**my.conf**:

```
[mysqld]
general_log=on
general_log_file=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
log_error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb_error.log
slow_query_log=on
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb_slow.log
long_query_time=2
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
innodb_file_per_table

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb_error.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid
```

tmpdir:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'tmpdir';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| tmpdir        | /tmp  |
+---------------+-------+
```

Thank you.

Comment: mariadb version? MariaDB configuration? I assume `datadir=/some/path/to/disk2`. Have you set [tmpdir](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#tmpdir) to disk2 as well? `lsof -p $(pidof mariadbd)` can quickly show the large file that MariaDB is creating.

Comment: @danblack: MariaDB version is 10.4.28. I added the configuration details to question.

Answer (score 2):

As `/data` is disk2 its important that MariaDB is configured to use this.

First, stop the MariaDB service (`systemctl stop mariadb.service`).

Second move your current MariaDB data to the disk2:

```
mv /var/lib/mysql /data/mariadb
```

Third, configure MariaDB to use this by changing `datadir=/data/mariadb` in the configuration. `socket` can be moved there too though be aware that other client programs might need to be told of the change too.

If running [selinux](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/selinux/#setting-the-file-context-for-the-data-directory) or [AppArmor](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start/#apparmor), follow the non-disabling instruction to ensure that this continues to work.

Also recommend:

- Not enabling the `general_log` except on a per session basis
- I suspect you might need a bigger [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_size) for your data.
- Increase [innodb_log_file_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_log_file_size) to several G, maybe more especially if doing a large amount of insert/updates to the database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I change the path of `tmpdir` as well?

Comment: its optional. Unless you are doing massive analytics requiring large temp tables either location should work.